# what is the best association for a campaign model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, associations

I am new to rails and still having association thinking, please in my try out project I want to do a campaign system, that people will pledge to vote but don't know how to handle this association to get back User referrals.
   Application logic
A user can only pledge once and in the process of pledging he has to select his referral who is also a User. How do I call a user object and ask for all is referrals?
   Model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :pledge

  has_secure_password

  VALID = /\A([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})\z/i

  validates :email, format: { with: VALID , on: :create }
  validates_confirmation_of :password
  validates_presence_of :password, :on => :create
  validates_presence_of [:email, :first_name, :last_name, :phone_number, :gender ]
  validates_uniqueness_of :email




  def signing_counter
    increment! :sign_in_count
  end


end

class Pledge < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  validates_acceptance_of :agreed
  validates_presence_of :commitment, :user_id
end
```

thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Refs < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :referal, :class_name => 'User'
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :refs
    has_many :referals, :through => :refs, :source => :referal
    has_many :refers, :through => :refs, :source => :user
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Generate User model:

```
rails g migration user name:string refer_id:integer
```

Single User can refer to multiple Users 
A User is referred/signed up by ONLY one User.

```
#user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :refers, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: 'refer_id'
    belongs_to :referred_by, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: 'refer_id'
end
```

Queries:

```
#gives the list of users to whom this first User refers.
User.first.refers 
#gives the user who has referred the first User.
User.first.referred_by
```

Comment: i ran in to this issue when i run:   User.last.refers
  User Load (2.3ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users`   ORDER BY `users`.`id` DESC LIMIT 1
  User Load (1.6ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users`  WHERE `users`.`refer_id` = 7
Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'users.refer_id' in 'where clause': SELECT `users`.* FROM `users`  WHERE `users`.`refer_id` = 7
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'users.refer_id' in 'where clause': SELECT `users`.* FROM `users`  WHERE `users`.`refer_id` = 7

Comment: Probably you are mixing up your existing code with mine. Try my codes in a fresh new sample example. This is going to work :)